# Is there a size limit on SyncML Command which can be sent to Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, mdm

Is there any size limit on the SyncML command that I can send to a Windows Phone 8.1 device (I'm using a Lumia 1320 to test.)? When I send the following SyncML command to the device, I get no response from the device:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><SyncML xmlns="SYNCML:SYNCML1.2"><SyncHdr/><SyncBody><Atomic><CmdID>InstallProfile</CmdID><Replace><CmdID>res-email-passcode.passwordpolicy</CmdID><Item><Data>0</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/DeviceLock/Provider/MEMDM/DevicePasswordEnabled</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/DeviceLock/Provider/MEMDM/AllowSimpleDevicePassword</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>4</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/DeviceLock/Provider/MEMDM/MinDevicePasswordLength</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/DeviceLock/Provider/MEMDM/AlphanumericDevicePasswordRequired</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>0</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/DeviceLock/Provider/MEMDM/DevicePasswordExpiration</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>0</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/DeviceLock/Provider/MEMDM/DevicePasswordHistory</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>0</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/DeviceLock/Provider/MEMDM/MaxDevicePasswordFailedAttempts</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>0</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/DeviceLock/Provider/MEMDM/MaxInactivityTimeDeviceLock</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/DeviceLock/Provider/MEMDM/MinDevicePasswordComplexCharacters</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item></Replace><Replace><CmdID>res-email-passcode.restrictionspolicy</CmdID><Item><Data>0</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/System/AllowStorageCard</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>0</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/Security/RequireDeviceEncryption</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>2</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/System/AllowTelemetry</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/Security/AllowManualRootCertificateInstallation</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/System/AllowUserToResetPhone</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/Experience/AllowSyncMySettings</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/Experience/AllowCortana</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/AboveLock/AllowActionCenterNotifications</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/Experience/AllowSharingOfOfficeFiles</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/Experience/AllowSaveAsOfOfficeFiles</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/Experience/AllowVoiceRecording</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/Search/AllowStoringImagesFromVisionSearch</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/Search/AllowSearchToUseLocation</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/Connectivity/AllowCellularDataRoaming</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/Connectivity/AllowUSBConnection</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/System/AllowLocation</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/Experience/AllowScreenCapture</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/Browser/AllowBrowser</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/ApplicationManagement/AllowStore</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/Accounts/AllowAddingNonMicrosoftAccountsManually</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/Experience/AllowCopyPaste</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/Connectivity/AllowVPNOverCellular</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/Connectivity/AllowVPNRoamingOverCellular</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>2</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/Connectivity/AllowBluetooth</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/WiFi/AllowManualWiFiConfiguration</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/WiFi/AllowWiFiHotSpotReporting</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/WiFi/AllowWiFi</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/WiFi/AllowInternetSharing</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/PolicyManager/My/WiFi/AllowAutoConnectToWiFiSenseHotspots</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item></Replace><Replace><CmdID>res-email-passcode.emailpolicy</CmdID><Item><Data/><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/EMAIL2/%7B4b3b88ed-9834-44c8-b767-8dc3472aea25%7D</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>node</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>Email</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/EMAIL2/%7B4b3b88ed-9834-44c8-b767-8dc3472aea25%7D/ACCOUNTTYPE</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>chr</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>some@email.com</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/EMAIL2/%7B4b3b88ed-9834-44c8-b767-8dc3472aea25%7D/AUTHNAME</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>chr</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>0</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/EMAIL2/%7B4b3b88ed-9834-44c8-b767-8dc3472aea25%7D/AUTHREQUIRED</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data/><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/EMAIL2/%7B4b3b88ed-9834-44c8-b767-8dc3472aea25%7D/AUTHSECRET</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>chr</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data/><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/EMAIL2/%7B4b3b88ed-9834-44c8-b767-8dc3472aea25%7D/DOMAIN</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>chr</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>-1</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/EMAIL2/%7B4b3b88ed-9834-44c8-b767-8dc3472aea25%7D/DWNDAY</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>chr</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>smtp:25</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/EMAIL2/%7B4b3b88ed-9834-44c8-b767-8dc3472aea25%7D/INSERVER</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>chr</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>15</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/EMAIL2/%7B4b3b88ed-9834-44c8-b767-8dc3472aea25%7D/LINGER</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>Some Mail</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/EMAIL2/%7B4b3b88ed-9834-44c8-b767-8dc3472aea25%7D/NAME</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>chr</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>smtp:25</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/EMAIL2/%7B4b3b88ed-9834-44c8-b767-8dc3472aea25%7D/OUTSERVER</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>chr</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data/><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/EMAIL2/%7B4b3b88ed-9834-44c8-b767-8dc3472aea25%7D/REPLYADDR</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>chr</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>EMail</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/EMAIL2/%7B4b3b88ed-9834-44c8-b767-8dc3472aea25%7D/SERVICENAME</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>chr</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>imap4</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/EMAIL2/%7B4b3b88ed-9834-44c8-b767-8dc3472aea25%7D/SERVICETYPE</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>chr</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data/><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/EMAIL2/%7B4b3b88ed-9834-44c8-b767-8dc3472aea25%7D/SMTPALTAUTHNAME</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>chr</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data/><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/EMAIL2/%7B4b3b88ed-9834-44c8-b767-8dc3472aea25%7D/SMTPALTDOMAIN</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>chr</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>0</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/EMAIL2/%7B4b3b88ed-9834-44c8-b767-8dc3472aea25%7D/SMTPALTENABLED</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>int</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data/><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/EMAIL2/%7B4b3b88ed-9834-44c8-b767-8dc3472aea25%7D/SMTPALTPASSWORD</LocURI></Target><Meta><Format>chr</Format></Meta></Item><Item><Data>0</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/EMAIL2/%7B4b3b88ed-9834-44c8-b767-8dc3472aea25%7D/TAGPROPS/8128000B</LocURI></Target></Item><Item><Data>0</Data><Target><LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/EMAIL2/%7B4b3b88ed-9834-44c8-b767-8dc3472aea25%7D/TAGPROPS/812C000B</LocURI></Target></Item></Replace></Atomic></SyncBody></SyncML>
```

However, if I reduce the number of items in the restriction command, I can get a response from the device. Sending the full restriction list separately also works. Is this due to the design of Windows Phone 8.1's MDM? Or am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out!

Apparently there is no significant size limit to the SyncML command. But there is for Apache Tomcat, on which the server was running. Tomcat limits the maximum size of a message to 8KB and any message beyond this would be "**chunked**" i.e. sent as a multi part message. Windows Phone 8 does not accept "chunked" messages.
The solution is to manually force Tomcat to send messages > 8KB as a single package by setting the buffer size for the response data in the servlet:

```
response.setBufferSize(responseData.length());
```

This would force Tomcat to send the whole message as a single package. And now the command works!